# What is the purpose of the 6.2 kΩ pulldown resistor in the GPIB interface?

Tags: gpib, ieee-488

Ie:
[image: GPIB Interface]

Dedicated chips exist, but older equipment use discrete components for this, where the output is often an open-collector gate/inverter. The purpose of the pullup is something I understand, but what is the purpose of the 6.2 kΩ pulldown? Is it to terminate the bus with a certain impedance? Just curious.

The GPIB control-lines are a type of wire-or, so that any or all devices can hold down (assert) say NDAC to control the bus speed. Thus the slowest device controls the speed of transfer.

Image is taken from here: http://bitsavers.org/pdf/hp/hpib/TutorialDescrOfHPIB.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Don't think of RL2 as a pulldown. Think of RL1 and RL2 together as a Thevnin termination.

They present an impedance of about 2k to an effective voltage of about 3.3 V.

As GPIB was designed to use TTL levels, a high voltage of 3.3 V is all that's needed.